# How to check if selected cells on a grid form a 'tunnel'?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, grid

Given a grid map where each cell can be described by a pair `(x, y)`, and a vector of such cells, how can I (nicely) check if the cells in that vector form a 'tunnel', ie. they are *all* lined up either vertically or horizontally? But what if I only want to see if *most* of them are lined up (and not *all*)?

```
All are lines up             Most are lined up      Not lined up

                             C                       C C C
 C C C C C C C C             C C C C C C C C         C   C C C
                                 C                   C C C C
                                                         C C
```

Comment: define "most". Can you also give a sample input of non-lined up? Though it seems obvious, a visual example could help answerers understand the problem at hand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate the [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) of both the X and Y coordinates. The more 'tunnelled' your cells are, the lower the std deviation will be for either X or Y.

For example, in Python:

```
import numpy

def is_tunnelled(cells):
    # given cells=[(x,y), (x,y),...]
    x_values, y_values = zip(*cells)
    lowest_std_dev = min(numpy.std(x_values), numpy.std(y_values))
    return lowest_std_dev < STD_DEVIATION_THRESHOLD
```

It's up to you to determine what the value of STD_DEVIATION_THRESHOLD should be.

Comment: This might be the best solution. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a histogram of the x and y coordinates of the cells.
If all cells are lined up horizontally, you get only one y-value in your histogramm and lots of consecutive x-values, which all occur only one times. Vertically is the same with x and y flipped.

If you want to check, if most of them are lined up, search for the value in the histogram, which has the most occurences (longest possible tunnel) and check the cells with that x or y-coordinate, if they are lined up (that is: their y or x-coordinates (depending on wheter x or y was used in the previous step) are consecutive without a gap (maybe sort them first))
If they are not, search for the second highest occurrence value, ...

Comment: "If you want to check, if most of them are lined up, search for the value in the histogram, which has the most occurences ..." Ah, obviously. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can check if they make a horizontal tunnel by first checking that their `y` coordinates are all equal, then sort by the `x` coordinate and traverse from left to right to check for gaps. Use the opposite coordinates to check for vertical tunnels.

For the approximate check you will have to clarify what you mean by "most".

Comment: I guess I could determine the percentage of cells that are lined up, then have the user decide what would be an acceptable tolerance (how many are allowed to deviate from the 'main tunnel' and still say that 'most are lined up').